# Lazy loading an youtube embedded iframe

Tags: lazy-loading, pagespeed-insights

So I am trying to speed up my loading time for SEO. All my articles have lazy loading right now, but one article does not seem to pick it up like the others.

[image]
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebexact.nl%2Fdoorway-pages

The article: [click here](https://webexact.nl/doorway-pages)

Now I am wondering what's wrong with the page. Thanks in advance.